# unable to send mail on SMTP port 25

Tags: java, smtp, port, jakarta-mail

I am unable to send mail as the SMTP port is getting blocked by McAfee antivirus as bulk mail. Of course if I disable it the mail works. But I just want to know how to avoid getting blocked. I noticed that applications such as thunderbird and outlook express do use the same SMTP port 25 (default) for outgoing mail and they do not get blocked.

The question is "is there any alternative ports that i can use or is there a way to avoid been detected as bulk mail, the same way as other email application such as outlook work?

Thanks & Regards,
Rajeev Nair.

Comment: "...is there a way to avoid been detected as bulk mail..." I certainly hope not:-)

Comment: Someone made a rule for outlook, so it can send mail. Nobody made a rule for Java, so it cannot. No miracles.

Comment: or could i use some other alternate port which would serve the purpose and do no get blocked by the anti-spyware? ..or maybe access outlook to send mail using java API ?

Answer (score 0):

you might need to add exception for your program, in order to be able to send email

Comment: I was thinking of other alternative options.

Comment: in that case create sending emails via outloock which is enabled allready

Answer (score 0):

It can work.  Try using port 587.  It has worked for me.